# Select data range when time and date are concatenated

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently using the line below to get the date

```
WHERE DATE (DateTime) BETWEEN '2016-12-19' AND '2016-12-23'
```

`12/12/2016 09:31` -  this is the date and time format

But it keeps on returning everything in the table from 2014.

The statement above seems to only work when its a short query but when I add a few lines to the SQL query it doesn't seem to work, Its extracting all dates in the table.

```
SELECT phone_number,system_outcome,DateTime
FROM calls 
WHERE DATE (DateTime) BETWEEN '2016-12-19' AND '2016-12-23'
AND system_outcome = 'ANSWER_MACHINE'
GROUP BY phone_number
HAVING count(Phone_number) > 6
```

Comment: you need to explain this *it doesn't seem to work.* Add sample data and expected result make things clear

Comment: What is the data type of the column `DateTime`?

Comment: Im not using field name DateTime i just selected the field to make sure the correct date was being selected.

Comment: timestamp_dtm is the name of the field

Comment: Please, rewrite the question using the real names, and show the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn to store dates in the correct format, not as a string.  You can fix your `where` clause using `date_format()`:

```
where date_format(left(date, 10), '%m/%d/%Y') between '2016-12-19' AND '2016-12-23'
```

I should also note that if you want phone numbers, then all other attributes should be the arguments of an aggregation function.  Say:

```
SELECT phone_number, system_outcome, group_concat(DateTime)
FROM calls 
WHERE date_format(left(date, 10), '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2016-12-19' AND '2016-12-23' AND
      system_outcome = 'ANSWER_MACHINE'
GROUP BY phone_number, system_outcome
HAVING count(Phone_number) > 6;
```